# generate 2 series from input serie optimally

Tags: python

consider this :

```
A,B=[],[]
for i in range(0,n):
    item=manipulate(data,i)
    A += [nextSerieA(data,i,item)]
    B += [nextSerieB(data,i,item)]

for a in A:
    doSmt(a)

for b in B:
    doSmt(b)
```

if `n` is very large number and `manipulate` takes long to execute ill wait for ever for `doSmt` to be called.

so i want to use generators to make `doSmt` start being called sooner for example :

```
def genA():
    for i in range(0,n):
        item=manipulate(data,i)
        yield nextSerieA(data,i,item)

def genB():
    for i in range(0,n):
        item=manipulate(data,i)
        yield nextSerieB(data,i,item)

for a in genA():
    doSmt(a)

for b in genB():
    doSmt(b)
```

The problem with this approach is that `manipulate` gets called twice for each item in the input serie, and in case manipulate is heavy operation its redundant and i want to avoid it.

The next step towards the most optimal code would be :

```
def manipulate():
    for i in range(0,n):
        yield i,manipulate(data,i)

def genA():
    for i,item in manipulate():
        yield nextSerieA(data,i,item)

def genB():
    for i,item in manipulate():
        yield nextSerieB(data,i,item)

for a in genA():
    doSmt(a)

for b in genB():
    doSmt(b)
```

but still `manipulate` will be called twice per input. whats the right way to get what i want and make sure its optimal, i.e `manipulate` called once per input item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) which uses queue under the hood to store the generated items.

```
def manipulate():
    for i in range(0,n):
        yield manipulate(data,i)
(genA,genB) = itertools.tee(manipulate())
```

It will save some computational resources as manipulate will be called one per item.

However, if the processing is sequential as in the example (first process genA and the genB), it will require significant auxiliary storage.